# I inhaled some solder fumes for a bit of time

Tags: protection, solder-mask

I inhaled some solder fumes while attempting a project last week, and I haven't stopped coughing since. It's getting rather irritating. However, I should mention that prior to my experiment, I had a cold, and strep throat. I'm aware searching the internet for an answer to a personal health concern is rather, quite stupid, but before running to a doctor I want to know if any of you have had a similar incident in which this has simply blown over, or find the incessant coughing to be the initial symptoms of something much larger.
Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a question about electrical engineering. If you have a health issue, see a doctor. That's the reasonable way of thinking.

Comment: I do know that soldering fumes cause asthma: http://www.occupationalasthma.com/occupational_asthma_causative_agent.aspx?id=82 maybe you're having related symptoms

Comment: I'm no doctor, but I'm going to go out on a limb and say that your cough and strep throat might be related.

Comment: I have been breathing solder fumes for almost 40 years and it hasn't done me any harm. I'm a hobbyist so it hasn't been daily but certainly once or twice a week.

Comment: I'm getting high on solder flux fumes 3 times a week. No health problems either. Go see a doctor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's completely unrelated to electronics design.

Comment: I was once concerned that I had inhaled harmful fumes after a long session (many hours) of continuous soldering with an unfamiliar brand of lead-free solder.  I suddenly developed strong flu-like symptoms the very same evening, it was uncanny.  I looked up the symptoms for... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_fume_fever and found that they matched my symptoms perfectly.  I went to the doctor because I felt like crap, and he told me that I had a respiratory virus.  So yeah the moral of the tale is that the interweb is no good for getting accurate medical info.  Go see a doctor.

Comment: Nobody would advise you to smoke, and likewise, nobody would advise you to breathe solder-flux fumes, and I'm not going to either. However, people live for years and die of other things doing both.

I explicitly minimise breathing flux fumes, without using an extractor. I take a deep breath before starting, and maintain a steady outflow while I'm soldering. It wouldn't be acceptable in industry, but it works for me as a hobbyist. What I do breathe is diluted by the volume of air in the room, and has been cooled down compared to straight off the iron.

Comment: most lead in your body is removed by the immune system. some looks like calcium and is erroneously stored. if you're growing fast, that's a much larger problem. if you're grown, it actually takes a lot of lead to develop any symptoms, and it doesn't happen overnight...

Comment: As with all things, what affects one person may not affect someone else. Just like some folks are allergic to Tylenol, you  may be more sensitized to flux fumes than most people. **HOWEVER**... if you have a cough that is persisting for more than a few days, GO SEE A DOCTOR, period. Never use the internet for research into health, you will never read anything that doesn't just make you sicker. Next time you do any soldering, make sure you use a fan across the workstation in a well ventilated area.... which is, BTW, good advice for everyone.

Comment: I personally consume 4 or 5 grams of vitaminC daily, when healthy. Under strep/pollen, I'll increase to as much as 20 or 30 grams a day, for several days; I merely drink 4-6 ounces of water with each gram. I've a friend with extensive travel in China; at any sign of "illness" he drinks 2 packets of emegenC every hour, for days.

Answer (score 1):

I've done soldering for long hours sometime back and inhaled solder fumes many a time. It is unsafe if you inhale too much, and causes temporary dizziness. However, it never resulted  in any other health issues.

I would suggest taking a break every few hours and go for a walk, if you have lot of soldering to do.

But, for now the best thing for you to do is to go to a doctor and get a medicine for your cold.